# AVD Crashes with "emulator64-x86 quit unexpectedly"

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have been trying to use an AVD with Android Studio 1.1.0 on OSX 10.10.2 and it runs OK until it crashes after a while saying "emulator64-x86 quit unexpectedly".

When I look at the crash report the exception type is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS where it's getting a KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007ffb7765fe90.

I have two other monitors hooked up and most solutions said to go change the `window.x` to 0 in the `emulator-user.ini` file, some said lock that file, some said disconnect your monitor, etc., but none of those solutions have worked for me.

One thing that might be related is that I'm setting the `network speed` and `network delay` to `gprs` so there are quite a bit of dropped packages and caught `SocketTimeoutExceptions` going on.

At this point, I'm willing to try anything because this doesn't allow me to test my app through various lifecycles and makes the testing impossible, not to mention frustrating.

Comment: If you're willing to "try anything"... get a real device. There's no way around it for proper testing. And you won't need three monitors, either ;) I wish it wasn't so, but Android emulators are simply not ready for professional work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do have a real device, in fact I have three but I want to control the network speed and delay which is hard to do in real life but very easy through the emulator... do you have any experience in doing real life network speed control maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it's too short for me to understand :P could you explain a bit more please?